# Installation error sas 9.3

Tags: windows, sas, installation, compatibility

After I reset my computer (Windows 10) I could no longer reinstall the sas 9.3 program. The following error appears:

```
"You've attempted to install software intended for one operating system on a
machine using a different operating system. You should either install on a
machine using the operating system you downloaded for or return to the download
site and download the appropriate software for your operating system."
```

I tried changing the compatibility, (Windows 7, XP, Windows 8) and did not work. I tried another installer and even the new version SAS 9.4 and nothing. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to contact your SAS sales representitive.  More than likely they need to get you a new set of license files and a new install depot.  SAS Tech support can confirm this for you.  http://support.sas.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing a specific version for Windows 10, which I got with Sas support.
Thanks, DomPazz!